# Do not render Angular container component without nesting

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am trying to create a component that reuses `ion-header`. With the way `ion-header` works, it needs to be a root component of the page (contained by nothing except `body`). I have looked into a couple of ways to do this:

- [Angular 2 - ngfor without wrapping in a container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37005007/angular-2-ngfor-without-wrapping-in-a-container)
- [Angular2 : render a component without its wrapping tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38716105/angular2-render-a-component-without-its-wrapping-tag)

I have created a component with an attribute selector:

```
@Component({
  selector: '[head]',
  template: `<ion-header>... {{head}} ...</ion-header>`,
})
export class HelloComponent  {
  @Input() head: string;
}
```

However, if I try to use `<ng-container head="The Title"></ng-container>` I get an error: `DOMException: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': This node type does not support this method.` from the Angular renderer itself.

I can update the template to include the content of `ion-header` itself and instead have `<ion-header head="The Title"></ion-header>`, but I would like to be able to reuse the component as a whole rather than having to specify the element and directive. This also prevents me from being able to include other attributes with `ion-header` if it's needed.

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fgfudn

Is there any way to render a component's template contents at the root level?

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is one convoluted way to do that, your component should have `ng-template` with `ion-header`. Then you create embedded view manually using component factory/resolver. This way you can render `ng-template` with `ion-header` right after your component tag (which can have display: none for example) on the same level.

Comment: Can you provide some code as an example of how to do this?

Comment: This is example with component, but templates are similar https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xkl1wh as you can see component is created below my-app